# Removing SYMLINK redirect

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

I have read with interest prior posts about finding redirects, both SYMLINKs and JUNCTIONS.  Running Windows 10.  Ran the following from the command prompt as administrator and got these results.

```
dir /AL /S C:\ | find "SYMLINK"
```

This gave a long list of SYMLINKs so I ran it again like this:

```
dir /AL /S C:\ | find "SYMLINKD"
```

This gave me this result:

```
12/07/2019 03:30 AM <SYMLINKD> All Users [C:\ProgramData]
```

So I gather that the system has a Symbolic link in place to move all new additions to the `ProgramData` directory over to the D: drive.
However, there is no `ProgramData` directory on the D: drive.  It was there in the past, with two subdirectories, but it is gone.
How do I remove the redirect?

I have read other threads suggesting to just delete the directory on the D: drive, but that directory is already deleted and it appears the redirect is still in place.

The ProgramData directory on the C: drive is substantial, with 3,326 folders and over 20 gigs of data.  I cannot take a chance of losing it but am concerned that future data for all programs will just disappear since it is redirected to a non-existent directory.

Further, I intend to remove the D: drive.  It is a partition on the SSD and I want to add that space back into the C: drive to avoid getting out of space errors.

Many threads about using `rmdir` under CMD or just deleting the directory in File Explorer, but the D: directory no longer exists and I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's quite hard to read this wall of text. Please format your post to make it more readable.

Comment: Sorry.  It looked fine when I reviewed it before submitting it, but I forgot to add the two spaces at the end of each paragraph.  Hope you can read it now.

Comment: I should also note that I have not found a way in PowerShell to search for redirects.  SYMLINK is not one of the items under Attributes you can search for.  Further, PowerShell help does not even recognize the term.  At least with the command prompt I could find the problem.